# is it possible for asp.net and a console application access the same semaphores?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, console-application

the idea is that a process (windows application console) creates the semaphores and a memory mapped file, and an asp.net application had to modify the memory mapped file.
When i try to do this operation from visual studio (IIS EXPRESS) all works, but when i try with the same code published on local (same machine) IIS, the asp application doesn't find the semaphores. where is the problem?

this is the .net application console code:

```
    Dim user As String = Environment.UserDomainName & "\" + Environment.UserName
    Dim mSec As New SemaphoreSecurity
    Dim rule As SemaphoreAccessRule = New SemaphoreAccessRule(user, SemaphoreRights.Synchronize Or SemaphoreRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Allow)
    mSec.AddAccessRule(rule)

    Dim emptyw = New Semaphore(0, 1, "MMF_EMPTY", True, mSec)
    Dim fullw = New Semaphore(1, 1, "MMF_FULL", True, mSec)
```

this is the asp.net code:

```
        Dim empty = New Semaphore(0, 1, "MMF_EMPTY")
        Dim full = New Semaphore(1, 1, "MMF_FULL")
```

Comment: Do the two processes run under the same account?

Comment: no, but i also tried to add manually the user IISPOOLAPPLICATION (the user who run the ASP.NET Code) and it didn't wrk.
but anyway, if they are different users, would the error be "unauthorized" insted of (doesn'exist)??

Comment: In IIS, there is a setting on the AppPool to generate a user environment profile, turning that on make any difference?

Comment: Turning it on makes no difference in the semaphores use.